# How to select middle child element from list view in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, listview

I am facing a little bit problem to add one CSS class to my list view elements. This list view element has some  children elements, which I want to add a class. Like

```
<li class="cmsCLI" data-type="first">
  <div class="cmsString">A</div>
  <div class="cmsString">B</div>
  <div class="cmsString **firstActive**">C</div>
  <div class="cmsString">D</div>
  <div class="cmsString">E</div>
  <div class="cmsString">F</div>
</li>
<li class="cmsCLI" data-type="middle">
  <div class="cmsString">A</div>
  <div class="cmsString">B</div>
  <div class="cmsString">C</div>
  <div class="cmsString">D</div>
  <div class="cmsString">E</div>
  <div class="cmsString">F</div>
</li>
<li class="cmsCLI" data-type="last">
  <div class="cmsString">A</div>
  <div class="cmsString">B</div>
  <div class="cmsString">C</div>
  <div class="cmsString">D</div>
  <div class="cmsString">E</div>
  <div class="cmsString **lastActive**">F</div>
</li>
```

According to above ListView, I want to add one class "active" in between from **firstActive** to **lastActive** class. I did like following steps.

At first, I retrieve the first active and lastActive class

```
var firstWrapper = window.jQuery('.cmsCLI').find('.cmsString[data-type="start"]');
var lastWrapper = window.jQuery('.cmsCLI').find('.cmsString[data-type="last"]'); 
var firstActive = window.jQuery(firstWrapper).find('.cmsCLI .firstActive'); 
var lastActive = window.jQuery(lastWrapper).find('.cmsCLI .lastActive');
```

Then I check the `firstActive.length` value and add the "active" class

```
if (firstActive.length > 0) {
  firstActive.nextUntil(lastActive ).addClass('active');
} else {
  var first = window.jQuery(lastActive).siblings('.cmsString:first'); 
  first.addClass('active');
  first.nextUntil(lastActive).addClass('active');
}
```

Here is adding 'active' class only `ListView[data-type="first"]` from "A" to "F" and `ListView[data-type="last"]` from "A" to "F". Unfortunately, the middle one `ListView[data-type="middle"]` is not adding any 'active' calss.

My query is how can I make active also middle Listview elements?
Thanks for your valuable time and efforts

Comment: It's not at all clear what output you're attempting to create with this logic, however I can tell you that `firstActive.nextUntil(lastActive)` will not work as you expect as `firstActive` and `lastActive` are not siblings.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your idea, I think you wanna add active class to all div tags with classname cmsString.

This query will add active to every .cmsString form firstActive to lastActive

```
var element = $('.cmsString');
var length = element.length; //length of element
var start = 0; // find index of firstActive
for(var i = 0; i< length; i++){
    if(element.eq(i).hasClass('firstActive')){
        start = i;
    }
}

for(var x = start; x<length; x++){
    element.eq(x).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below logic!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag = false;
  $(".cmsString").each(function(index, value) {
    if (!flag && $(value).hasClass('firstActive')) {
      flag = true;
      $(value).addClass('active');
    } else if (flag) {
      $(value).addClass('active');
      if ($(value).hasClass('lastActive'))
        flag = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cmsCLI" data-type="first">
  <div class="cmsString">A</div>
  <div class="cmsString">B</div>
  <div class="cmsString firstActive">C</div>
  <div class="cmsString">D</div>
  <div class="cmsString">E</div>
  <div class="cmsString">F</div>
</li>
<li class="cmsCLI" data-type="middle">
  <div class="cmsString">A</div>
  <div class="cmsString">B</div>
  <div class="cmsString">C</div>
  <div class="cmsString">D</div>
  <div class="cmsString">E</div>
  <div class="cmsString">F</div>
</li>
<li class="cmsCLI" data-type="last">
  <div class="cmsString">A</div>
  <div class="cmsString">B</div>
  <div class="cmsString">C</div>
  <div class="cmsString lastActive">D</div>
  <div class="cmsString">E</div>
  <div class="cmsString">F</div>
</li>
```